# Validación de correo electrónico

Tags: javascript, jquery, formularios, email, webforms

Buen día. Tengo un problema que me está llevando días en resolver. Sucede que tengo que elaborar un campo con validación de email, es decir que valide la información antes de hacer consulta al servidor si el formato ingresado es válido (un script en js), estrictamente. Esta validación es sencilla de hacer.

Ahora viene lo complejo. Se requiere que le sugiera al usuario con un texto, que digite el dominio correctamente. Algo similar a: "Quizás quisiste decir nombre@gmail.com", y que realice validación con una lista de dominios públicos y privados.
[image: Sugerencia al usuario]

Espero que alguien de esta comunidad me de luces para poder ejecutar este script. Gracias.

Comment: Yo utilizaría mejor un validador externo, pero obviamente esos cobran tipo briteverify. El problema con los correos electrónicos en su dominio, es que existen  infinidad de dominios. Saludos!

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 0):

yo considero que existen diferentes maneras de abordar el problema, unas mas complejas que otras, pero en cualquier vas a tener que tener una base de datos con los dominios aceptados por tu plataforma.

Una de las soluciones que se me ocurre de momento es la siguiente:

Creas una base de datos con los dominios que están aceptados, cuando la persona escriba el correo, comparas el texto que se encuentra despues del @ y antes del punto, si no hace match con ningún valor de la base de datos entonces despliegas el error y le muestras las posibles soluciones encontradas (que van a hacer los dominios que hacen un 60% de match o superior)

```
correo= "algo@gamil.com"
domino = correo.split("@")[1].split(".")[0] // dominio = "gamil"
percentOfWord = 0;
posibleWord = []
dominiosAceptados = ["google", "yahoo", "outlook"]

if(dominiosAceptados.include(dominio) === false)
{
   dominiosAceptados.foreach(
      (unDominio)=>{
         for(int i=0, i< dominio.length, i++){
            if(unDominio.indexOf(dominio[i]) !== -1){
              percentOfWord += 100/(dominio.length); // Porcentaje de precisión
            }
          if(percentOfWord > 60)
          {
             posibleWord.push(unDominio);
          }
          percentOfWord = 0;
        }
      }
   )
}
```

Está solucion te sirve para comparar dominios especificos, como te comento, es solo una solución que tambien tiene varias desventajas, pero quizá te sirva para tener una base de donde arrancar.

Algunas posibles desventajas son:

- La cantidad de dominios existentes es infinita, por lo tanto, si mi dominio no se encuentra en tu base de datos el script va a encontrar un error y no me va a permitir avanzar.
- La base de datos puede ser gigante, por lo tanto la mejor forma de comparar el texto es usando metodos de aprendizaje de lenguaje natural.

Ojala encuentres una solución y puedas resolver tu problema!, muchos exitos.

Answer (score 0):

Te puse un ejmplo de cómo lo haría, ya no valido si tiene un arroba porque al poner que el input sea de tipo `email` si no agregar un arroba no te dejará pasar, comente el código, espero te des una idea.

```js
let email = document.getElementById('correo');

let dominios = new Array('gmail.com', 'outlook.es','hotmail.com','yahoo.com'); //creo un arreglo con los dominios aceptados

email.addEventListener('blur', function(){


if(email.value == '' || email.value == 'undefined'){
    console.log('El campo es obligatorio');
    return false;

}
 let value = email.value.split('@'); //split() funciona para dividir una cadena en un array pasando un caracter como delimitador
    
    console.log(value[1]);
    
    if(dominios.indexOf(value[1]) == -1){ //.indexOf() sirve para encontrar un elemento en un array
      
     console.log('dominio no encontrado'); 
     dominios.forEach(function(dominio){ //utilizamos forEach para recorrer el arreglo.
        
          console.log(`Los dominios aceptados son: ${dominio}`);
     
     })
      return false;
    }else{
      
        console.log('dominio aceptado');
    
    }

});
```

```html
<input type="email" id="correo">
```